# Print Pictures, why is it so difficult

Tags: php, google-chrome, printing, imagick

I have asked this before I believe but i'm having more issues with it. I have got a web application that runs on a local server. When the user adds sales to an image, a page is generated with all the sales.

This consists of images, with the amount of images changing depending on how many sales have been made. These images can vary between landscape and portrait. In order to print the images they must ALL be rotated to portrait, so I use PHP and Imagick to detect the width and height and rotate them accordingly.

So, here is an example page with 5 images ready to be printed.

```
<div class="print_container" id="print_container" style="display: block;">
    <div data-type="KR">
        <img onload="c++;count_loaded();" id="LKR_6_0" data-quantity="2" onclick="disable_print(this,'print_container')" src="http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/generateimage.php?imgname=C:/xampp/htdocs/ppa/data/images/20140324/0/039.JPG&amp;restraint=width" class="">
        <img onload="c++;count_loaded();" id="LKR_6_1" data-quantity="2" onclick="disable_print(this,'print_container')" src="http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/generateimage.php?imgname=C:/xampp/htdocs/ppa/data/images/20140324/0/039.JPG&amp;restraint=width" class="">
        <img onload="c++;count_loaded();" id="LKR_7_0" data-quantity="2" onclick="disable_print(this,'print_container')" src="http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/generateimage.php?imgname=C:/xampp/htdocs/ppa/data/images/20140324/0/040.JPG&amp;restraint=width" class="">
        <img onload="c++;count_loaded();" id="LKR_7_1" data-quantity="2" onclick="disable_print(this,'print_container')" src="http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/generateimage.php?imgname=C:/xampp/htdocs/ppa/data/images/20140324/0/040.JPG&amp;restraint=width" class="">
        <img onload="c++;count_loaded();" id="LKR_13_0" data-quantity="3" onclick="disable_print(this,'print_container')" src="http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/generateimage.php?imgname=C:/xampp/htdocs/ppa/data/images/20140324/2/039.JPG&amp;restraint=width" class="">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I link to a PHP file and get the image returned from there. What would be nice is a way to detect if the same image is being rotate and just instance it for duplicates instead of rotating it multiple times, but that it's the issue at the moment.

Here is the code which generates the image:

```
<?php
//Need to add code to generate image if unable to load
try {
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImage($_GET['imgname']);
    $im->setImageFormat("jpg");

    $d = $im->getImageGeometry();
    $w = $d['width'];
    $h = $d['height'];

    if (isset($_GET['restraint'])) {
        if($_GET['restraint'] == "width") {
            if ($w > $h) {
                $im->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(), 90);
            }
        } elseif ($_GET['restraint'] == "height") {
            if ($w < $h) {
                $im->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(), 90);
            }
        }
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        print $im->getImage(); 
        $im->clear(); 
        $im->destroy(); 
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error when creating a image: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

All the above seems to work fine, but when I can to print the images with Google Chrome, sometimes the Print Preview fails, which I don't mind as I will be disabling that as it's pointless. But printing using the system print dialog also does not work, it simply doesn't print and gives no errors. So i'm assuming the issues are linked...?

Is it possible to send TOO MUCH data to the print job? 
P.S My print is connected over WiFi if that makes any difference?

Comment: People voting to close the UNANSWERED question but not giving a decent reason at all, oh how helpful you are...